# Mutiple Sending of Data to Database Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, conditional-statements

Logic: I have this range option in dropdown. It has numbers from 1-12 which represents the number of months the client will pay. When I select "1", there's no problem since I'll just be saving one date. But if I select "2", I should be able to save same data twice and the date will be in a consecutive manner so there will be 2records to be made in one click. (Example: 9/9/13 and 10/9/13) Same goes with three and up. Can someone help me? This is in codeigniter. Thanks.

Model:

```
  function add_payment($id, $keyid, $key, $paymentdate, $forpaymentdate, $datecreated, $subscription_type){
    $this->db->set('keyid', $keyid);
    $this->db->set('key',$key);
    $this->db->set('paymentdate',$paymentdate);
    $this->db->set('forpaymentdate',$forpaymentdate);
    $this->db->set('userid','0');
    $this->db->set('notified','0');
    $this->db->set('subscription_type', $subscription_type);
    $this->db->insert('payment');
}
```

Controller:

```
function save_payment(){
    $id = @$_POST['id'];
$keyid = @$_POST['keyid'];
$key = @$_POST['key'];
$dateofpayment = @$_POST['dateofpayment'];
$forpaymentdate = @$_POST['forpaymentdate'];
$datecreated = @$_POST['datecreated'];
$subscription_type = @$_POST['subscription_type'];
//$userid = $_POST['userid'];
//$notified = $_POST['notified'];

$this->operation->add_payment($id, $keyid, $key, $dateofpayment, $forpaymentdate, $datecreated, $subscription_type);
    die(redirect(base_url('system/payment?status=saved')));

    }
```

Comment: post your insert code

Comment: which field is the dropdown value

Comment: if payment months > 1, then Loop. create a constant with the first date and then add a day to it each time you Loop. Insert into your table.